# If the bicep connects closely to the elbow joint, would the bicep need to exert more or less force to lift an object?

Tags: forces, torque, biophysics

I would like to know whether a less or large amount of force is exerted by the bicep to lift and hold an object if the bicep is connected close to the elbow joint (fulcrum) than if the bicep is connected more closely to the wrist. Why? And does torque play a role in this?

Answer (score 1):

To figure this out you can use the pivot formula. If the applied force $F_A$ is distance $r_A$ from the fulcrum and the exerted force, $F_E$, is distance $r_E$ from the fulcrum, then 
$$
F_E=F_A\times r_A/r_E.
$$
If the bicep is connected close too the elbow joint it will have a smaller $r_E$ than if it is connected close to the wrist. Therefore, if the bicep is connected close too the elbow joint it will need a larger exerted force than if it is connected close to the wrist.

Comment: In brachiating primates, the bicep is connected farther from the elbow joint, providing greater exerted force at the hand.  In human beings, the ability to throw rocks fast is evolutionarily important.  Although the exerted force at the hand may be less, the speed at the hand (at a specific speed of muscle contraction), can be much greater for  a human arm than for the arm of a brachiating ape.